# Determining if Heroku app is loading quickly

Tags: heroku, load, load-time

I recently signed up for Heroku and created a landing page. I want to know if users are waiting only reasonable amounts of time for the page to load when they click on one of my ads. [Blitz.io](http://blog.blitz.io/2011/05/how-many-dynos-do-i-need-on-heroku/) seems like overkill. What might be the simplest alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to track this stuff is probably the [New Relic](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) Heroku addon. Just provision it, turn it on, and it'll generate response time graphs for you. They have a free plan as well.

I'm not at all affiliated with New Relic -- just been using it happily for a while.